# Splitting by Tabs in Java

Tags: java, string, split

I have a file scanned line by line into an ArrayList. 
I then create a new ArrayList in which I want to temporarily store that line into so that I may access certain values.

Ex. IDname(tab)IDnumber(tab)vote(tab)date

So, I create the temporary ArrayList named voteSubmission, and I go through every String in the fileRead array.

**Why is it that I get the error incompatible type for my split method?**

```
ArrayList<String> voteSubmission = new ArrayList<String>(); 
for(String x : fileRead)
{
voteSubmission =  x.split("\t");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`split` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) returns an array, not an `ArrayList`.

Either work with an array or convert it to an `ArrayList` manually.

Answer (score 2):

`x.split("\t");` this function will return an array not array list

The [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) function states that:

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
>
> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> the array of strings computed by splitting this string around matches
>   of the given regular expression

You may try to change your code like this:

```
ArrayList<String> voteSubmission = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    for(String x : fileRead)
    {
        for(String value: x.split("\t"))
        {
            voteSubmission.add(value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to ArrayList<String>`

Which means that `x.split("\t")` provides a `String[]` array, but you assign it to an `ArrayList`.

If you'd like it to be an ArrayList, you'd have to convert it like this:

```
new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(x.split("\t")));
```

But since you are doing this in a loop it is likely that you would like to store all Arrays within the ArrayList. To do this, you have to create an ArrayList of type String[], like this:

```
ArrayList<String[]> voteSubmission = new ArrayList<String[]>(); 
for(String x : fileRead){
  voteSubmission.add((x.split("\t")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of split() is of type string[] array and you are trying to assign to an ArrayList type, which is incompatible.

Change your code to

```
ArrayList<String> voteSubmission = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    for(String x : fileRead)
    {
        String arr[] = x.split("\t");
        if(arr != null && arr.length > 0)
        {
           for(String value: arr)
           {
              voteSubmission.add(value);
           }
        }
    }
```